# Bold and Italic text depending on data in WPF ComboBox, without XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a CustomControl that is derived from ComboBox and I would like to show certain items with Bold text, some with Italic and some normal, depending on associated data.  Since there's no XAML associated with this, I am having trouble finding a way to handle this.  The items are DataBound to the control via the ItemsSource property so each item type is just the Object type for my data object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) for your custom ComboBox
with overriding ComboBox's [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx)

```
<CustomComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbTitle" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Style}" Value="0">
                <Setter TargetName="tbTitle" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>                      
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Style}" Value="1">
                <Setter TargetName="tbTitle" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter TargetName="tbTitle" Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</CustomComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The `CustomCombobox`'s ItemSource is collection of a simple object with a string property `Title` And an  int property `Style`